# JTable replaces line returns with spaces after multilined text is copied/pasted into cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

As soon as I copy and paste a string with multiple lines into a jtable cell, the line returns are replaced with spaces that make the entry a single line string. How do I keep from losing the line returns? I don't care how it is displayed within the JTable cell. I only care that when I extract the text, I still have the line returns.

Here is the part of the code where I am printing out the data that I just entered:

```
table.getModel().addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener(){
    public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e){
        int row = e.getFirstRow();
        int column = e.getColumn();
        if(row >=0 and column >=0){
            TableModel tmodel = (TableModel)e.getSource();
            Object data = tmodel.getValueAt(row,column);
            //As soon as I enter the multilined text, it prints it out here without line returns
            System.out.println(data.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my table model's setValueAt method:

```
public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col){
{
     data[row][col] = value;
     fireTableCellUpdated(row,col);
}
```

Comment: The code you're showing prints the column name, not the data. Also post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for better help.

Comment: Why are you calling `getColumnName()`, don't you mean `getValueAt(row, column)`? Make sure that the integrity of the strings is being preserved in your setValueAt method of your TableModel. How is the data stored?

Comment: @DSquare Yes, sorry. I just didn't copy it right.

Comment: @peeskillet, Thanks, I fixed the code. I don't think that I need to post a working example because this must be the default behavior of JTable.

Comment: I don't mean that I fixed the problem, I just fixed the part that I didn't copy correctly getColumnName() instead of getValueAt();